# Meld window is stuck maximized in GNOME. How to restore?

Tags: gnome, meld

Somehow I maximized meld in GNOME and now it is stuck in full screen and I can't change the size.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling but it fails to change anything.

I will try to purge meld and hopefully that will restore the default behavior.

Is there a menu for use with meld?

How do I get out of full screen?

Answer (score 0):

Just hit <kbd>F11</kbd> to take it out of fullscreen mode.

Hopefully, this will help someone else.